# 'reflect back on' or 'reflect on' some event in the past?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

As the title suggests, should I use "reflect back on" or "reflect on" when talking about something in the past?

For example:

> I find myself reflecting on the journey that has led me to where I am today.

> I find myself reflecting back on the journey that has led me to where I am today.

Comment: ...back is not required. REFLECT alone should be enough.

Comment: Idiomatically, and logically, 'look back on' is common. 'Reflect' contains the idea of 'back'.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: @Nigel - I don't agree that "reflect" contains the idea of "back". What about, "I reflect on the journey that I am about to take"?  The element " that has led me", is what tells us the journey is in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find myself reflecting on the journey.

In this sentence, we don't know when the journey happened. We could have

*As I sit on this train, I find myself reflecting on the journey that I am undertaking right now.* (present journey)

*As I sit in this café, I find myself reflecting on the journey that got me here.*  (past journey)

*Sitting at home, I find myself reflecting on the journey that I will undertake next Summer.* (future journey)

In English, and most European languages, the past is considered to be behind us. We look back to the past and we look forward to the future.

In this context, "reflect" is almost synonymous with "think".

> 4. VERB When you reflect on something, you think deeply about it. We should all give ourselves time to reflect. [VERB]  I reflected on the
>    child's future. [VERB + on/upon]  Synonyms: consider, think,
>    contemplate, deliberate
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reflect

Thus, "I think forward to the journey"  means the journey is in the future and "I think back to the journey" means it is in the past.

**Answer**

*I find myself reflecting on the journey that has led me to where I am today.*  (This is correct)

*I find myself reflecting back on the journey.* (This is correct)

*I find myself reflecting back on the journey that has led me to where I am today.*  (This is tautological because the past is indicated in two ways, (1) "back" and (2) "has led me")

Answer (score 0):

“Reflect back” is redundant. To reflect means you are thinking about something in the past. You contemplate about something happening in the present. You don’t reflect.

Comment: Hello, P. Sorry, this is wrong. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reflect) includes << **reflect** B2 to think carefully, especially about possibilities and opinions:
• The manager demanded time to reflect (on what to do).... / • It provides one with a chance to reflect on spiritual matters in solitude. / • The writer reflects on human injustice and iniquity. / • In many of his poems the poet reflects on the quietude of the countryside. / • He paused for a moment and reflected on the work in front of him. >> 'Take a moment to reflect on the beauty ...

Comment: of the Cotswolds countryside.' 'Reflect' in the 'think deeply about' sense may well be used for memories, but can also be used for contemplation in general. Hence 'reflect back' is valid (though so is 'reflect'), specifying 'on past occurrences etc'. See chasly's answer.